# Is there a way to pass a size to `enum_for`/`to_enum`?

Tags: ruby

I work a lot with a 2d-grid of elements and I sometimes need to enumerate over these elements, so I have a class that looks like this:

```rb
class Grid
  def initialize(width, height)
    @elements = Array.new(width * height, DEFAULT_ELEMENT)
  end

  def each(&block)
    return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?

    @elements.each(&block)

    return self
  end
end
```

This has been working fine forever, but only today did I realize that the `Enumerator` returned by `#each` does not lazily calculate the size. I could manually define an `Enumerator`, but I have quite a few enumerators besides `each` and that would be tedious.

So I was wondering if there is something like `enum_for(:method, lazy_size)`, so that I can write `enum_for(:each width * height)`.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "lazily calculate the size"?

Comment: @sawa `Enumerable#count` has to enumerate the whole collection, whereas `Enumerator#size` attempts to calculate the size *lazily*, i.e. without enumeration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a block to [`enum_for`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Object.html#method-i-enum_for) that calculates the enum's size:

```
enum_for(:each) { width * height }
```

Comment: Obviously... I tried passing extra arguments, but that didn't work. But this is ruby, passing a block always does the trick :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to support various types of enumerator, may be you should consider implementing [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html) mixin

```
DEFAULT_ELEMENT = ":"

class Grid
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(width, height)
    @elements = Array.new(width * height, DEFAULT_ELEMENT)
  end

  def each
    @elements.each {|i| yield i}
  end

end


p Grid.new(2,2).map {|i| "#{i}-)"}
#=> [":-)", ":-)", ":-)", ":-)"]

p Grid.new(4,6).count
#=> 24
```

Comment: And yes, `#count` will work on any Enumerator, but it is O(n), not O(1).